# Sending POST request with custom header

Tags: php, blogger

I am trying to implement the blogger [v3 api to create a new post](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#AddingAPost).

Here is my PHP code that should post the request to server but it returns a error

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3333333333333/posts/):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
>   in /var/www/html/playscript.prijm.com/TempFiles/1449828856x.php on line 24
>   bool(false)

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $blog_id = 'dddddddddddddd';
    $api_key = 'AIzaccccccccccKUCKo';

    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/'.$blog_id.'/posts/';
    $data = '{
      "kind": "blogger#post",
      "blog": {
        "id": "'.$blog_id.'"
      },
      "title": "A new post",
      "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
    }';

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: ".$api_key."\r\nContent-type: application/json\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $data,
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: It's pretty obvious that your request needs authorization and most likely, you need to perform an Oauth 2.0 authentication and get hold of a Oauth token before sending requests.

Comment: I understand, but i was only asked for the api key!

Comment: In the first section of the "Using the API page" from the google devs website says that: Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. After that it's described what have to do to achieve that. You should read the API docs more carefully :)